# printf a float value with precision (number of decimal digits) passed in a variable

Tags: c, floating-point, printf, string-formatting, precision

I can print a float value with precision of 3 decimal digits with

```
double f = 1.23456;
printf( "%.3f", f );
```

Now I have the number of requested decimal digits that is not fixed but stored into a variable

```
int precision;
precision = atoi( argv[ 1 ] ); // ...just for example
double f = 1.23456;
```

How do I print the value of `f` with the number of decimal digits specified in `precision` ?

I can programmatically compose the format string for `printf` but I'm wondering if there is a more simple way to do it.

Comment: Your use of `precision` is not precise enough.  What output would you want for 1234567000 and 0.0001234567 with "precision of 3 digits"?

Comment: I meant decimal digits. You're right I fixed the question

Comment: So with `0.0001234567`, code should output `0.000` or something else?

Comment: With `0.0001234567` should output `0.000`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `".*"`

```
printf("%.*f", precision, f);
```

Example:

```
>>> printf("%.*f", 5, 3.14)
"3.14000"
```

## Precision

This is called the precision field. 
According to the [man pages](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf),

> The precision: An optional precision, in the form of a period ('.') followed by an optional decimal digit string. Instead of a decimal digit string one may write "*" or "*m$" (for some decimal integer m) to specify that the precision is given in the next argument, or in the m-th argument, respectively, which must be of type int. **If the precision is given as just '.', or the precision is negative, the precision is taken to be zero**. This gives the minimum number of digits to appear for d, i, o, u, x, and X conversions, the number of digits to appear after the radix character for a, A, e, E, f, and F conversions, the maximum number of significant digits for g and G conversions, or the maximum number of characters to be printed from a string for s and S conversions.

## Width

The width field is similar and works for more formats, such as `"%*s"`. Just remove the `.`.
It will pad the output with spaces or zeros as needed.
If `precision` is negative, the string will be left-aligned.

```
>>> printf("%*s\n", 10, "left?")
"     left?"
>>> printf("%*s\n", -10, "left?")
"left?     "
```

According to the [man pages](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf),

> The field width: An optional decimal digit string (with nonzero first digit) specifying a minimum field width. If the converted value has fewer characters than the field width, it will be padded with spaces on the left (or right, if the left-adjustment flag has been given). Instead of a decimal digit string one may write "*" or "*m$" (for some decimal integer m) to specify that the field width is given in the next argument, or in the m-th argument, respectively, which must be of type int. **A negative field width is taken as a '-' flag followed by a positive field width.** In no case does a nonexistent or small field width cause truncation of a field; if the result of a conversion is wider than the field width, the field is expanded to contain the conversion result.

Comment: Pedantic detail: the type of `precision` needs to be something, after the usual promotions, is type `int`.  Unclear about OP's `uint`.

Comment: Now I get it, precision must be **before** the actual value. No wonder my code didn't work...