# How to add zeros after the significant digits after decimal in C?

Tags: c, formatting, printf

```
double r;
float a;
scanf("%lf",&r);
a=M_PI*pow(r,2);
printf("%.*f",6,a);
```

The output is 12.566371
but I want the output like this 12.560000.

So I want total 6 digits after decimal but only 2 digits from original answer and the remaining digits to be 0.

Comment: Read about the format specifier of printf. It is all there...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [printf a float value with precision (number of decimal digits) passed in a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35121029/printf-a-float-value-with-precision-number-of-decimal-digits-passed-in-a-varia)

Comment: And I understand you just want to print a bunch of zeroes, even when the digits are actually _not_ zero. That would give the user the impression the answer printed is exact up to all digits printed when actually it is _not_. That is bad practice.

Comment: Why did you use `"%.2f"`? Maybe the answer to this question answers **your** question :)

Comment: Priyam Sharma, What input do you use to get "output is 12.566371"

Comment: After the edit: try `"%.2f0000"`

Comment: -pmg Thanks it worked
-kvantour Printing in the format i described is mandatory for the question i was solving.It is part of college programming  lab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... total 6 digits after decimal but only 2 digits from original answer and the remaining digits to be 0.

Print the rounded answer to the desired precision and then print the zeros with `"%0*d", zeros, 0`.

Or post process text to get an un-rounded output.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#ifndef M_PI
#define M_PI 3.1415926535897932384626433832795
#endif

int main() {
  double r = 2.0;
  double a = M_PI * pow(r, 2);

  int total_digits_after_decimal = 6;
  int zeros = 4;
  printf("%.*f%0*d\n", total_digits_after_decimal - zeros, a, zeros, 0);

  char buf[4096];
  int len = sprintf(buf, "%.*f", total_digits_after_decimal, a);
  buf[len - zeros] = '\0';
  printf("%s%0*d\n", buf, zeros, 0);

  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
12.570000
12.560000
```

---

Note: The approach of `printf("%.*f",6,trunc(a*100)/100);` works for many values of `a` yet fails when `a` is very large and for select values when `a*100` is inexact and near a whole number value.

---

The usually challenges occur of how to handle infinite and not-a-number.

The buffer size worst case could use `DBL_MAX_10_EXP` (often 308) to right size `buf[]`.

```
#include <float.h>
//     sign        digits     .             precision         \0
char buf[1 + DBL_MAX_10_EXP + 1 + total_digits_after_decimal + 1];
```

---

Deeper:

The post processed approach still rounds the answer but at the 6th decimal place rather than the 2nd.

To incur no rounding, the precision needs to extend out about at least `DBL_DECIMAL_DIG` (C11) places or `total_digits_after_decimal + 1` - which ever is greater.  This insures text output is rounded beyond what might affect things.

```
  int len = sprintf(buf, "%.*f", DBL_DECIMAL_DIG, a);
  buf[len - DBL_DECIMAL_DIG - (total_digits_after_decimal - zeros)] = '\0';
  printf("%s%0*d\n", buf, zeros, 0);
```

---

Take heed of [@Paul Ogilvie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53745664/how-to-add-zeros-after-the-significant-digits-after-decimal-in-c-programming-lan/53746271#comment94343727_53745664) good advice.  The coding goal here is questionable for production code.

Users like [@kvantour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53745664/how-to-add-zeros-after-the-significant-digits-after-decimal-in-c-programming-lan/53746271#comment94346341_53745664) echo the questionable need for this curious goal.

Comment: Thanks it worked.Can you tell how to print only 2 digits after decimal without rounding off i.e. exactly 2 digits from answer.
eg. answer is 12.566371
but i want 12.56 only not 12.560000

Comment: Thanks I understood the code.Now I wam able to get the correct output!

Comment: Initially I was using the value of Pi from math module and getting output 2.57..
but when I used the value of pi=3.14 I got the answer as 2.56..

Comment: @PriyamSharma  A portable way to determine machine pi (π to the best that system provides) is to do a one time calculation of  `pi = acos(-1.0);`.  Still, I find using a constant with twice the expected decimals needed robust for current and subsequent applications.  Using `3.14` is not a good approach.